# Utilize xml-rpc from T-SQL code

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xml-rpc

Currently I have nice solutions for REST (via clr/assembly) and SOAP (via sp_OA based stored procedure) but XML-RPC is still a question to access directly from SQL Server T-SQL code.

Please advise which variants exist for this purpose.

I need to avoid application layer because all logic is already in a stored procedure inside the database, and just recordset is needed to be supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have consumed XML from an HTTP call within t-sql using the xmlhttp COM object, which looks something like:

```
Declare @Object as Int;

Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', 
NULL, 'get',
'http://www.webservicex.com  /stockquote.asmx?symbol=MSFT',                                                                'false'

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

Select @ResponseText

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

The xml in @ResponseText can then be shredded via traditional tsql methods.

This isn't a particularly robust method;  Using an SSIS package or CLR integration would most likely yield a better solution, but this is one way to keep it all within t-sql.

See:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/eac9c027-db71-48ae-872d-381359d7fb51/